# Copy Jar file to docker container using Docker command

Tags: java, spring, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I copy the jar file without specifying the version in the copy command?

Below is the original command

```
COPY web-app/target/web-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar /web-service.jar
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use that docker file in my spring projects: with a docker compose up command it runs.

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD dockerspringboot.jar dockerspringboot.jar
EXPOSE 8094
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dockerspringboot.jar"]
```

Comment: I should use the Add command instead of Copy, and I don't need to care about the version number? Please advise.

Comment: Why don't you use wild cards ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786035/docker-copy-with-folder-wildcards